# How to decode a CKRecord NSData field, created by a transformable CoreData attribute, back to its original type?

Tags: core-data, cloudkit, ckrecord, transformable

**Setup:**

My app uses CoreData & CloudKit sync.
Entity `Item` has among others an attribute `status` of type `Int16` with corresponding property `@NSManaged var status: Int16`, and an attribute `names` of type `transformable` using `NSSecureUnarchiveFromDataTransformer` with corresponding property `@NSManaged var names: Set<String>?`

To get notified when iCloud records change, the app uses a query subscription.
When a notification is delivered, an identifier of the changed object is sent, the `objectID` of the `NSManagedObject` is obtained, and the corresponding `ckRecord: CKRecord` is fetched using `persistentContainer.record(for: objectID)` of `persistentContainer: NSPersistentCloudKitContainer` to get the actual property values.

**Question:**

"normal" field values, e.g. `status`, can easily be obtained using `ckRecord["CD_status"] as! Int16`. I can also get `ckRecord["CD_names"] as! NSData`, but I don't know how to convert it back to `Set<String>?`.

Comment: I guess `NSSecureUnarchiveFromDataTransformer(). transformedValue(ckRecord["CD_names"] as! NSData)` might work? But I think that `NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchivedObject(ofClasses:from:)` might be enough.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I used let `names = NSSecureUnarchiveFromDataTransformer(). transformedValue(ckRecord["CD_names"])`and it works (as with `as! NSData`)! Please make your comment to an answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Types for properties are limited to some types in CoreData, `Set<String>` not being one, that's why you need a transformer, that will transform it into `(NS)Data`.

So, you could use that transformer to transform it back with `transformedValue(_:)`:

```
NSSecureUnarchiveFromDataTransformer().transformedValue(ckRecord["CD_names"])
```